# replace value in an numpy ndarrary

Tags: python, numpy

suppose I have an n dimensions numpy array as below, is there a way I can change all 255 in the last element of the nested arrary to 0? thanks

`[
[1,2,3,255],
[1,2,3,234],
[1,2,3,255],
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,255,3,255], [1,2,3,234], [1,2,3,255],])
>>> a
array([[  1, 255,   3, 255],
       [  1,   2,   3, 234],
       [  1,   2,   3, 255]])

>>> a[a[:,-1] == 255, -1] = 0  # <---
>>> a
array([[  1, 255,   3,   0],
       [  1,   2,   3, 234],
       [  1,   2,   3,   0]])
```

Comment: hi, this needs to be limited to the last element of the array, looks like you example will replace all 255 regardless whether the 255 is in the last index of the array?

Comment: @JohnZ, You'd better to modify the example array in the question to make it clear. For example: `[ [1,255,3,255], [1,2,3,234], [1,2,3,255], ]`

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that contains values in the last columns, than change the values by boolean array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[255,2,3,255], [1,2,3,234], [1,2,3,255]])
b = a[:, -1]
b[b==255] = 0
print a
```

result:

```
array([[255,   2,   3,   0],
       [  1,   2,   3, 234],
       [  1,   2,   3,   0]])
```